how to install nest trader using wine in linux
i tried to install nest trader using wine in ubuntu after i installed it ends in not responding and it asks me to forcequit the software


You've tagged you're using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ; is that correct?

Only fully supported releases of Ubuntu (standard support) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in extended support and now Ubuntu 14.04 ESM thus only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage and off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Check with https://www.winehq.org. Not all Windows programs are available through wine. This is not a Ubuntu problem, this is a wine problem.
